# PHP function for checking POST security and storing variable

Tags: php, html, function, post, http-post

I am looking for information on how to make a function to make this easier. I know there is an easier way then writing the posted variable I want into PHP.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  $name =   isset($_POST['name']) ? htmlentities($_POST['name']) : '';
  $email =  isset($_POST['email']) ? htmlentities($_POST['email']) : '';
  $interest = isset($_POST['interest']) ? htmlentities($_POST['interest']) : '';
  $checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? htmlentities($_POST['checkbox']) : '';
```

So far I came up with a function like this:

```
function req_post($n){
  '$'$n = isset($_POST["$n"]) ? htmlentities($_POST["$n"]) : '';
}
```

I know I am doing this wrong, kinda new to PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You really shouldn't be `htmlentities`ing your inputs. That's a job only for outputs.

Comment: why are you doning this ? For SQL injection ? use PDO and have a great life.

Comment: I don't get this: '$'$n =

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might seem tempting to make functions like this, seemingly removing duplicate code etc but it always ends up biting you in the end.

Your code shows you escaping all the POST data ready for the next environment which will be a html page.

So, if you are outputting $email only to a html page, its seemingly worth it.

BUT if you are outputting to both a webpage "Thank you $email" and also storing this to a db then you have not escaped it for the db, so you risk sql injection attacks.

Until you know better, you are best off leaving $_POST['email'] as it is and escaping it as you output it.

```
echo htmlentities($_POST['email']);
```

OR

```
$query = 'update names set email = "'.mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']).'" where ID =1';
```

OR PREFERABLY using PDO/Mysqli and prepared statements, which do this escaping for you.

**htmlentities** is a method of escaping for html output
**mysql_real_escape_string** is a method of escaping for mysql databases (though outmoded, as has been said by me and others).

The fact is that if you come across a var like $email you will be left thinking, now hang on, is this escaped ready for the next environment? Where did it come from?

When you see $_POST['email'] you know you are dealing with potentially very dirty and dangerous data, and you handle it with care.

You would be far better off spending your time doing some filtering and maybe deciding that if $_POST['email'] (or name or whatever) is indeed empty, what to do next -- relocate the user, show a warning to the user and so on.

The mnemonic FIEO provides the basic rule, Filter Input, Escape Output and you can save yourself a lot of future pain by spending a couple of hours researching it.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I actually am using PDO to post this information for a database.

I didn't realize I was using htmlentities wrong!

Does this mean I would be okay with just using this?

`$interest = isset($_POST['interest'])`

Comment: Do var_dump($_POST) and see what is sent when that element is submitted empty.  If that passes your "business rules", ie an empty string going into my db is acceptable, and leaving interest empty is acceptable, then just put the $_POST['interest'] straight into your prepared statement. However if interest is chosen from a drop list of say 4 interests, then you should be Filtering the incoming interest by checking that it is indeed one of those 4 permitted values.  Otherwise, a business rule kicks in and you abort, relocate the user or something like that.

Comment: Very insightful.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

```
//If you intend to put into database and you need to use a function

function clean($value){
$array = array("name", "email", "interest", "checkbox"); //For added security
   if(isset($_POST[$value]) && in_array($value, $array)){ //Since you are only concerned with post;
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connection, $_POST[$value]); //and YES, use mysqli - forget what is deprecated in future projects
 }
}

$clean_name = clean("name");
$clean_email = clean("email");
$clean_interest = clean("interest");
$clean_checkbox = clean("checkbox");

echo $clean_email;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function htmlentities_and_checkISset($string){

    $result = isset($string) ? htmlentities($string) : '';

    return $result
}
```

Or do this

```
function htmlentities_and_checkISset(){


        // get number of arguments in this function
         $numargs = func_num_args();

         // get arguments comming to the function
         $arg_list = func_get_args();

         // for each arg do the thing you want and then store it in an array
         for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {

         $data[] = isset($arg_list[$i]) ? htmlentities($arg_list[$i]) : '';

        }

     return $data;
    }
```

and you can call it like this.

```
$data = htmlentities_and_checkISset($name,$email,$interest,$checkbox);
```

Or

```
 $data = htmlentities_and_checkISset($_POST['name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['interest'],$_POST['checkbox']);
```

Comment: Checking `isset` on variables inside that function is pointless, because the variables are guaranteed to *be set* there. Especially when you're looping through a list of arguments, don't you think those'd be set?

Comment: @deceze I did it for the `htmlentities` he can call the isset function before calling the function.